# What technique they used earlier to make idols stand for centuries

Tags: temple, practice, customs, idols

We all know there are lot of Hinduism temples where idols are standing from many centuries best example is Lord Venktaeshwara in Tirumala, Tirupati.

This idol is standing from many centuries it survived from those many thousands of years. What construction technique they used earlier to establish a idol in temple to last so long? For example nowadays they use cement to establish idol in temples but cement were not available during those time, so what was the technique they used to make idols stand and survive for so long?

I am sure people say Lord Balaji is self manifested not built by human being (but there must be some sort of physical support right for idol to stand), but there many idols established by saints like Adi Shankara etc. So what they used in-lieu of cement to establish an idol?

Can anyone please shed some light on this? I am confused from many years on this topic!

Comment: Lord venkateshwara is a self manifested idol.It doesn't need any support. Why is it must that there would be some physical support to it? FYI He stands on a Padma peetham in Tirumala hills.

Comment: Venkateshwara Swamy is a swayambhu shaligrama it is not made by any human being such beauty cannot be sculpted by any mortal. Why don't you question swayambhu Jyotirlinga they are also self manifest. Adi Shankrachrya has nothing to do with Tirupati temple. Bhagwad Ramanujacharya preserved this temple or it would've been taken over by atheists or non Vaishnavas.

Comment: Hi people, thanks for comments, I gave Venkateshwara Swamty just as example. I generally want to know how idols in temple are made stand for so many years and what technique of shastras they use to establish idol in temples!

Comment: And @Yogi FYI please don't take it as debate between Vaishnavas or Non-Vaishnavas it's very irrelevant here!

Comment: I am not taking in that direction I am stating truth what bhagwad Ramanujacharya did, even adi Shankaracharya reestablished many temples from nastikas giving them a good lesson.

Answer (score 1):

The primary reason for the long lasting strength of idols in most of the temples are the choice of Granite for sculpting the idol. Even though the granites appear to be similar in appearance, their strength and durability are decided by various factors like cracks in outer layer, porosity etc.,

The Granite(rocks) of high quality are used for building pillars and supporting beams, where as low quality would be used for pavements.

Even though the deciding factor of selction of making idols are not clearly known, we can very well say that choice of the Granite is one of the predominant reason for long lasting strength of idols.

More over, the abishegams performed on the idol like thaila-kapu and the choice of abishegam material may also enhance the strength of the idols.